# Using Notepad++ to replace only a part of the text

Tags: notepad++, regex

In a html file I want to replace

```
<div id="pe1" style="display:none">
<div id="pe2" style="display:none">
....
<div id="pe20" style="display:none">
```

with

```
<div id="pe1" style="border:2px solid black">
...
<div id="pe2" style="border:2px solid black">
<div id="pe20" style="border:2px solid black">
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the replace dialog with those parameters:

Select "Regular expressions" in the "search mode" box.

Search what: `<div id="pe(\d+)" style="display:none">`

Replace with: `<div id="pe\1" style="border:2px solid black">`

The parenthesis in the search expression allow you to use the `\1` in the replace (the parenthesis define a capturing group, and \1 refers to the first one), and `\d+` stands for "one or more digits".